# Need Java Swing equivalent of "scrollIntoView" from Browser DOM

Tags: java, swing, scroll

I have a JPanel with several levels of child components, also with a JScrollPane.  I'm placing a focus listener on some of the child components to add some behavior to those components, but I would also like to have that component scroll into the JPanel's viewport when focus is gained.

My question is, does anyone have a general purpose function to do this, similar to the browser DOM function "scrollIntoView"?  I've tried muddling through this with various inputs to JComponent.scrollRectToVisible but I guess I haven't figured out the magic word.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious thing is to call `scrollRectToVisible` on is the JScrollPane, which will compile fine but won't do what you want. You must call `scrollRectToVisible` on the object contained in viewport of the scrollpane. The code should look sort of like:

```
java.awt.Component focusedComponent = evt.getComponent();
panel.scrollRectToVisible(focusedComponent.getBounds(null));
repaint();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  That was one of the things that I thought I tried, but I guess I did it incorrectly.  Thanks eugener!